# Java Orika Mapper

Tags: java, spring, entity, dto, data-mapper

Здраствуйте. У меня есть PostEntity, PostDto и есть OrikaMapper.

```
package com.egsians.dto;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PostDto {

    private Long id;
    private Long userId;
    private String text;
    private Date date;
    private List<HashTagDto> hashTags;
    private List<ImageDto> images;

}

package com.egsians.model;
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "posts_id_IDX", columnList = "id"),
        @Index(name = "posts_user_id_IDX", columnList = "user_id")
})
public class PostEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private UserEntity user;

    @Column(name = "text", nullable = false, length = 1000)
    private String text;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date date;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    private List<ImageEntity> images;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "posts_hash_tags",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "hash_tag_id")
    )
    private List<HashTagEntity> hashTags;
}




 package com.egsians.mapper;

import com.egsians.dto.HashTagDto;
import com.egsians.dto.ImageDto;
import com.egsians.dto.PostDto;
import com.egsians.model.PostEntity;
import com.egsians.model.UserEntity;
import com.egsians.repository.UserRepository;
import ma.glasnost.orika.CustomMapper;
import ma.glasnost.orika.MapperFactory;
import ma.glasnost.orika.MappingContext;
import ma.glasnost.orika.impl.ConfigurableMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Component
public class PostMapper extends ConfigurableMapper {
    private final UserRepository userRepo;
    private final HashTagMapper hashTagMapper;
    private final ImageMapper imageMapper;

    public PostMapper(UserRepository userRepo,
                      HashTagMapper hashTagMapper,
                      ImageMapper imageMapper) {
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
        this.hashTagMapper = hashTagMapper;
        this.imageMapper = imageMapper;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(MapperFactory factory) {

        factory.classMap(PostEntity.class, PostDto.class)
               .customize(new CustomMapper<PostEntity, PostDto>() {
                   @Override
                   public void mapAtoB(PostEntity postEntity, PostDto postDto, MappingContext context) {
                       postDto.setUserId(postEntity.getUser().getId());
                       postDto.setId(postEntity.getId());
                       postDto.setDate(postEntity.getDate());
                       postDto.setText(postEntity.getText());
                       postDto.setHashTags(postEntity.getHashTags()
                               .stream().map(hashTag -> hashTagMapper.map(hashTag, HashTagDto.class))
                               .collect(Collectors.toList()));
                       postDto.setImages(postEntity.getImages()
                               .stream().map(image -> imageMapper.map(image, ImageDto.class))
                               .collect(Collectors.toList()));
                   }
               })
                .register();

        factory.classMap(PostDto.class, PostEntity.class)
                .field("id", "id")
                .field("text", "text")
                .field("date", "date")
                .field("hashTags", "hashTags")
                .field("images", "images")
                .byDefault()
                .customize(new CustomMapper<PostDto, PostEntity>() {
                    @Override
                    public void mapAtoB(PostDto postDto, PostEntity postEntity, MappingContext context) {
                        Optional<UserEntity> optionalUser = userRepo.findById(postDto.getUserId());
                        optionalUser.ifPresent(postEntity::setUser);
                    }
                }).register();
    }
}
```

Когда вызываю метод postMapper.map(postEntity,PostDto.class), он мне выдает результат, в котором поле userId всегда null. Можно ли как нибудь исправить?

Comment: Переведите, пж-та, вопрос на русский язык.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В PostMapper есть класс CustomMapper, а в нем метод mapAToB. Так как я работаю с Spring Boot-ом, мне помог аннотатия `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`, поставленный перед методом mapAToB.